# save excel worksheet to csv format with macro too large

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook which consists of 4 worksheets. With this macro, I've outscaled one of the worksheets, which works great, but the file size will be about 10x the size of the workbook. The workbook will be 9Mb, the worksheet saved in csv format will be 93Mb. If I open the worksheet and save it, it will be 1Mb. Maybe wrong code or what could be the problem to solve? I use M365.

```
Sub cssexport1()
    
    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo err
    
    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "cikkek-feltoltes" & ".csv"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cikkfeltöltő").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    With tempWB
        .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
        .Close
    End With 
err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: What format is the 1Mb file ? How many rows and columns of data ?

Comment: same csv, line 3959

Comment: xlsx files are stored in a zipped/compressed file structure, but a plain-text CSV is not, so it's not so surprising the CSV is larger.

Comment: I found the error. I deleted everything from the Excel worksheet and the worksheet I wanted to save: it was completely blank. The file size was still 2Mb. I deleted the worksheet, created another with the same content. In a matter of moments, the csv file was quickly created, which was 1Mb in size. It must have been some Excel bug...